# Message:1031 Arithmetic overflow in prolog

Tags: prolog

predicates

```
nondeterm s(integer,integer)  
nondeterm p(integer,integer,integer)
```

clauses

```
s(V,R) :-
    p(0,V,R).

%,write(R),nl.

p(R,0,R).

p(Inc,V,R) :-
    I2=Inc+V,
    N1=V-1,
    p(I2,N1,R).
```

goal

```
s(9,O).
```

gives an arithmetic overflow,,,why??

Comment: When I run this with SWI-Prolog I get `ERROR: Out of global stack`. What Prolog are you using? Is this the same error you get. Is so please be more specific when writing a question.

Comment: No , I use visual prolog 5.2

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog mathematical expressions are not done with assignment, e.g. `=`. Prolog does not use assignment like many common programming languages, Prolog uses unification. If you want to do math expressions in Prolog and unify the result with a variable then you need to use the is/2 operator

```
I2 is Inc+V
N1 is V-1
```

You also need a guard statement to keep the second clause from being executed if the second parameter is 0.

```
s(V,O) :-
    p(0,V,O).

p(R,0,R).

p(Inc,V,R) :-
    V \= 0,
    I2 is Inc+V,
    N1 is V-1,
    p(I2,N1,R).
```

Now your query returns

```
?- s(9,O).
O = 45 ;
false.
```

Comment: It doesn't work ,I need to sum integers from N to 1 and return the result ??

Comment: @AmmarEL-Hagary That was only a partial answer to show you why it failed which answered your question. Since it was an easy set of predicates I then corrected it so it would work. That was not part of your question.

Comment: when I remove V \= 0 from code it will gives me the same error as exist a result with this error and when i let it it doesn't affect and give aresult only ...why

Comment: `when I remove V \= 0 from code it will gives me the same error as exist a result with this error and when i let it it doesn't affect and give a result only ...why` That is an additional question. You need to post that as a new question. I will not be answering that question in this answer as StackOverflow is not a site for discussions. If I answer that here then you will pick up a bad habit.

Comment: I don't enforce you to answer or not...
up to you

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Guy's answer, it is instructive to run your query in the Prolog tracer as it clearly shows that, because you used unification (`=/2`) instead of arithmetic expression evaluation (`is/2`), your query build an increasingly bigger compound term at each recursive call until the global stack space is exhausted:

```
[trace]  ?- s(9,O).
   Call: (8) s(9, _3176) ? creep
   Call: (9) p(0, 9, _3176) ? creep
   Call: (10) _3396=0+9 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 0+9=0+9 ? creep
   Call: (10) _3402=9-1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 9-1=9-1 ? creep
   Call: (10) p(0+9, 9-1, _3176) ? creep
   Call: (11) _3408=0+9+(9-1) ? creep
   Exit: (11) 0+9+(9-1)=0+9+(9-1) ? creep
   Call: (11) _3414=9-1-1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 9-1-1=9-1-1 ? creep
   Call: (11) p(0+9+(9-1), 9-1-1, _3176) ? creep
   Call: (12) _3420=0+9+(9-1)+(9-1-1) ? creep
   Exit: (12) 0+9+(9-1)+(9-1-1)=0+9+(9-1)+(9-1-1) ? creep
   Call: (12) _3426=9-1-1-1 ?
   ...
```